# how do I get past an smtp limit?

Tags: linux, smtp

We have a website hosted on a shared hosting plan. It works for now but we are running over our limit for smtp emails. Our host charges us for anything over 250 emails sent. We send out daily alerts, password reminders, etc to our users (on an opt-in basis w/ the ability for them to easily opt-out).

Can we use our localhost server for email but still host the site on the remotehost? If not, are there any other (free) options?

Comment: localhost is a linux box and we can setup the mail server, but just want to make sure it's possible b/f we go down that road....we tested php's mail() but the emails get routed to the junkmail folder. We are boostrapping so the cheaper the solution the better.

Comment: can I just change the email server on my domain's zone file settings? If so, what do I change? I have email, e, smtp, webmail, pop, imap...do I just change ALL of them to my remotehost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you already send mail from your local server?  If so, have the code in your web site pack up the information that needs to be sent that day into one email.  You'll have to figure out the format to use so that you can separate them on the other end.  Send it to a mailbox on your local host that is monitored by a process that unpacks the email, splits it up into separate emails, and sends those out directly.  If your web host has a size limit on emails, you'll need to figure out how to break your daily output into chunks to avoid going over the size limit as well.

Or, pay a little extra to be able to send out more emails per month from your web host, which would be less complex, less prone to errors, and easier to implement.